Smart-contract works on local node and Sepolia but not Polygon Amoy
I have an ERC20 Token that I'm testing and I'd like to deploy on Polygon PoS.
I deployed it on Polygon Amoy and for example, every time I call the approve method, my transaction fail.
I then tested to deploy it on Sepolia and my transaction works perfectly.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";

contract MyERC20 is ERC20Capped, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Pausable, Ownable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor()
    ERC20("My ERC20", "TOTOERC20")
    Ownable(msg.sender)
    ERC20Permit("My ERC20")
    ERC20Capped(10000000 * 10 ** decimals())
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 value)
    internal
    override(ERC20, ERC20Pausable, ERC20Capped)
    {
        require(!paused(), "ERC20Pausable: cannot transfer while paused");
        super._update(from, to, value);
    }

    function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) public override onlyOwner {
        super.burnFrom(account, amount);
    }

    function burn(uint256 amount) public override onlyOwner {
        super.burn(amount);
    }
}

Any idea what difference could cause it to fail on some blockchain but work on other ?
Could it be some compiler option like evm version ?

Some L2 networks do not upgrade their nodes to support the latest EVM opcodes. You could force solc to use a previous EVM version, or downgrade to a previous solc compiler. I'd start with solc 0.8.23 or 0.8.24.
